# Safe print (e.g. avoid terminal control sequences)

Tags: perl, terminal, printf

How to sanitize string before printing or print safely?
I would like to remove all terminal control sequences and other potentially risky sequences.

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14707

Comment: The sequence to clear the screen is typically `"\e[H\e[2J"`, where `\e` denotes the ASCII escape character. Is the sanitized version of that sequence `"[H[2J"` or `""`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of focusing on what you want to remove, perhaps you can specify the characters that you want to keep.  The following is a regex to remove anything that is not a word character, spacing, or punctuation:

```
s/[^\w\s[:punct:]]+//g;
```

The following demonstrates for a couple of sample lines.  It uses [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to conveniently display the internals of the strings:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my @data = (
    "Hello World\t\r\n\e\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x0b",
    'Testing Punctuation - `~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:";\'<>?,./'
);

for (@data) {
    print "   Orig: " . dump($_) . "\n";
    s/[^\w\s[:punct:]]+//g;
    print "Cleaned: " . dump($_) . "\n\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
   Orig: "Hello World\t\r\n\e\0\1\2\3\4\13"
Cleaned: "Hello World\t\r\n"

   Orig: "Testing Punctuation - `~!\@#\$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\\:\";'<>?,./"
Cleaned: "Testing Punctuation - `~!\@#\$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\\:\";'<>?,./"
```

Answer (score 0):

The translation may be:

```
$str =~ tr/\x00-\x08\x0B-\x1F\x7F//;
```

That is the ASCII control characters excluding tab and line feed.

Answer (score 0):

This way might work, depending on what you need: it removes everything that's not alphanumeric or whitespace:

```
my $junk  = "\t\r\n\e  hello\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x0b";

print length($junk), "\n";  # 17
$junk =~ s/[^\w\s]//g;
print length($junk), "\n\n";  # 10

my $junk2 = "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x0b";

print length($junk2), "\n";  # 6
$junk2 =~ s/[^\w\s]//g;
print length($junk2), "\n";  # 0
```